# Elasticsearch batch not indexing all items using PHP client

Tags: php, elasticsearch, amazon-opensearch

I've been trying to build an index in ES and add the initial items to it (around 350k), using PHP.

I tried all kinds of batch sizes (from 10 items to 1k), check the count, check the threshold, but for some reason it doesn't index every item.

It just skips over some random items, without any errors in the batch result response. I feel like I tried everything and I have to idea what to do next

I'm using Amazon OpenSearch with the latest supported ES (7.10).

The index looks like this:

```
{
    "wonder-search": {
        "aliases": {},
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "address": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "city": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "city_id": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "duration": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "filename": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "geo_point": {
                    "type": "geo_point"
                },
                "icon": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "is_sandbox": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "item_id": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "item_label": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "latitude": {
                    "type": "float"
                },
                "longitude": {
                    "type": "float"
                },
                "search_text_caption_json": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "index_phrases": true
                },
                "search_text_city_json": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "index_phrases": true
                },
                "search_text_completion": {
                    "type": "completion",
                    "analyzer": "simple",
                    "preserve_separators": true,
                    "preserve_position_increments": true,
                    "max_input_length": 50,
                    "contexts": [
                        {
                            "name": "type",
                            "type": "CATEGORY"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "search_text_country_json": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "index_phrases": true
                },
                "search_text_cuisine_name_json": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "index_phrases": true
                },
                "search_text_location_name_json": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "index_phrases": true
                },
                "search_text_state_json": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "index_phrases": true
                },
                "search_text_tag_name_json": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "index_phrases": true
                },
                "search_text_username_json": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "index_phrases": true
                },
                "sort": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "sort_score": {
                    "type": "double"
                },
                "type": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "user_icon": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "user_id": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "username": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "vanity_url": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "video_count": {
                    "type": "integer"
                }
            }
        },
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                "routing": {
                    "allocation": {
                        "include": {
                            "_tier_preference": "data_content"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "mapping": {
                    "ignore_malformed": "true"
                },
                "number_of_shards": "1",
                "provided_name": "wonder-search",
                "creation_date": "1671003076106",
                "number_of_replicas": "1",
                "uuid": "YQh1q40WTneLE4MWDWhArw",
                "version": {
                    "created": "7100199"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and one item looks like this:

```
{
    "_index": "wonder-search",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "wq2LD4UBUAuy7FQPhtZh",
    "_version": 1,
    "_seq_no": 2003,
    "_primary_term": 1,
    "found": true,
    "_source": {
        "sort": "4004",
        "item_id": "4934",
        "user_id": "434",
        "user_icon": "/site-content/avatars/Sp8AXjTJvMbRao2oZbuiUuSVH042-1597776099045.jpeg",
        "username": "chuurros",
        "item_label": "Kyoto Katsugyu【京都勝牛】",
        "search_text_username_json": [
            "chuurros"
        ],
        "search_text_caption_json": [
            "Absolutely love their gyukatsu (beef katsu) here! Delicious and will keep you wanting more! "
        ],
        "search_text_city_json": [
            "Toronto"
        ],
        "search_text_state_json": [
            "Ontario"
        ],
        "search_text_country_json": [
            "Canada"
        ],
        "search_text_location_name_json": [
            "Kyoto Katsugyu【京都勝牛】"
        ],
        "search_text_tag_name_json": [
            "japanese",
            "restaurant",
            "asian",
            "dining",
            "topcollection-4934"
        ],
        "search_text_cuisine_name_json": [],
        "type": "video",
        "vanity_url": "",
        "icon": "",
        "city": "Toronto",
        "city_id": "439",
        "latitude": "43.65682410",
        "longitude": "-79.37617410",
        "address": "134 Dundas St E",
        "duration": "9.57",
        "video_count": "0",
        "sort_score": "43",
        "filename": "373d75fd-4292-4e5b-a239-4b1c39ffc86c.MOV",
        "is_sandbox": "0",
        "geo_point": {
            "lat": "43.65682410",
            "lon": "-79.37617410"
        },
        "search_text_completion": {
            "input": [
                "Kyoto Katsugyu【京都勝牛】"
            ],
            "contexts": {
                "type": [
                    "video"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas why does it work like this?

Comment: can you add more detail

Comment: @Amit not sure what else to add. I've been working with ES for about 3 weeks now. I start the batch using a PHP command directly from an EC2 instance and I have a loop that goes through the data from a MySQL instance and builds the array

Comment: @Amit looking for anything in particular?

Comment: Any ideas why does it work like this? means what, what is not working for you?/

Comment: @Amit oh, I wrote in the beginning. It just skips (doesn't add to index) over some random items, without any errors in the batch result response.